# Debugging Android on Acer Iconia Tab A100

Tags: android, debugging, tablet

I'm developing an tablet application and I have an Acer Iconia Tab A100 with Android 3.2 Honeycomb which I want to use for testing and debugging.

I'm using Eclipse with ADT plugin for development. Everything works in the emulator and on my Samsung Galaxy SII phone, but my tablet doesn't appear in the list of devices.

I downloaded the latest USB Drivers from Acer, but nothing changes. I can see my tablet in Windows Explorer as mobile device and I can access the memory from within Explorer.

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP ?  Install Media Player 11.  Needs that for MTP device.  You'll find NOTHING on the Acer site(s) about this. Found it by accident on a forum.  Took me months.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on debug-gable? I assume you have but just encase go settings > applications > development > debug-gable

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but debuggable is turned on.